# rails prevent object creation in before_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I want to check some attributes of the new record, and if certain condition is true, prevent the object from creation:

```
before_create :check_if_exists

def check_if_exists
  if condition
    #logic for not creating the object here
  end
end
```

I am also open for better solutions!

I need this to prevent occasional repeated API calls.

Comment: you're touching callbacks hell. Next step: you'll remove them from your models and abstract those behaviours in service objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a uniqueness validator too... in fact is a better approach  as they are meant for those situations.

Another thing with the callback is that you have to be sure that it returns `true` (or a truthy value) if everything is fine, because if the callback returns `false` or `nil`, it will not be saved (and if your `if` condition evaluates to `false` and nothing else is run after that, as you have written as example, your method will return `nil` causing your record to not be saved)

[The docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) and [The guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: I want to validate the uniqueness of post.body within the scope of discussion, where it is being created. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: `validates :body, uniqueness: {scope: :discussion_id}` is probably what you are looking for. With old hash syntax: `validates :body, :uniqueness => {:scope => :discussion_id}`

Answer (score 14):

```
before_create :check_if_exists

def check_if_exists
  errors[:base] << "Add your validation message here"
  return false if condition_fails
end
```

**Better approach:**

Instead of choosing callbacks, you should consider using validation here.Validation will definitely prevent object creation if condition fails.  Hope it helps.

```
  validate :save_object?
  private: 
   def save_object?
     unless condition_satisifed
       errors[:attribute] << "Your validation message here"
       return false
     end
   end
```

Comment: thanks! validations are better than callback in this case, definitely! upvote