# How to use before_save (with params) to check if a record exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to check if a record exist before_save, what's the best way tod do that ?

```
def create
  @step = Step.new(step_params)
  @course = Course.find(step_params[:course_id])
  redirect_to course_path(@course) and return if step_already_present?(@step)

  if @step.save
    redirect_to course_path(@course.id)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The method to check :

```
def step_already_present?(step)
  Step.where(poi_start_id: step.poi_start_id, course_id: step.course_id).first.present?
end
```

Comment: Did you consider using a [uniqueness validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)?

Comment: There's a really good approach for this here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041930/5870350

I would also look into .exists? over .present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the uniqueness validation on the Model

If you need to check the two columns together you can use the scope option like this:

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :poi_start_id, uniqueness: { scope: :course_id }
end
```

Comment: How can I redirect_to a specific location if the validation fail ?

Comment: @Ben, if your step.save fails on controller, you can check by step.errors and redirect to a specific location inside the else block